# Movie Texture not playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer and i'm trying to get a title card to pop up at the beginning of each stage, like the ones in the original sonic games. To achieve this i'm going to have a movie texture in front of the camera and then once it's finished playing, it moves away. However, the movie texture isn't playing. I've attached the script and all that but I just get a black box. Can any one help? Here's the script even though it looks right.

```
var MovieTex : MovieTexture;

function Start(){

    renderer.material.mainTexture = MovieTex;
    MovieTex.Play();
}
```

Comment: What does MovieTex.isPlaying return? And I'm assuming that you're using Unity3D Pro, as this is a pro feature I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Unity Pro

Comment: What does MovieTex.isPlaying return?